# Getting Nivo-slider to start before all images are loaded

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

I am using the Nivo-slider Wordpress plugin, and love how it looks and how easy it is for my clients to use.

The only problem is that the slideshows do not play until all the images are loaded, which is a big problem as soon as you have more than a few images: http://www.marcusmcshane.com/

Does anyone know how to make the slideshow start after the first couple have loaded?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Having had plenty of experience with Nivo Slider personally, I remember that they use `$(window).load` which I indeed saw you are still using too.

**Change this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    jQuery("#nivoslider-283").nivoSlider({
        effect:"fade",
        slices:15,
        boxCols:8,
        boxRows:4,
        animSpeed:500,
        pauseTime:3000,
        startSlide:0,
        directionNav:false,
        directionNavHide:true,
        controlNav:false,
        keyboardNav:true,
        pauseOnHover:true,
        manualAdvance:false
    });
});
</script>
```

**to this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("#nivoslider-283").nivoSlider({
        effect:"fade",
        slices:15,
        boxCols:8,
        boxRows:4,
        animSpeed:500,
        pauseTime:3000,
        startSlide:0,
        directionNav:false,
        directionNavHide:true,
        controlNav:false,
        keyboardNav:true,
        pauseOnHover:true,
        manualAdvance:false
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Although now it loads before the logo, so I have to look into that...

For those also using the plugin, in nivo-slider.php line 841 I simply changed `jQuery(window).load(function(){` to `jQuery(function(){`.

Comment: And then enjoy fixing this again and again with every update. I would recommend using Royal Slider.

Answer (score 0):

This is still relevant to each new Nivo Slider clean install & Caroline's solution works fine.

I keep an adjusted copy for design use with any tweaks (like the above) included, therefore no need to keep changing it.

Saving:

```
    jQuery(function(){
$('#slider').nivoSlider();   });
```

..as a separate file (nivo.js) & calling it from the html file means it's easily found to adjust or return to original if need be.

For added peace of mind define the height of a div (#slider) so the page doesn't pop around in slow loading browsers.