# Better performance for slideshows

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, slideshow

In a recent project, I used Nivo Slider to build a slideshow. This is a solid solution, with useful options, but my users complain that it is slow to load. And they are right, because the script needs all the images loaded to run.

I am looking for tips to improve performance, and maybe recommendations on solutions to replace Nivo Slider. I mean of course advice beyond the obvious (like using lighter images and reducing the total number of slides).

Edit: to clarify the context, the images are pulled from a gallery maintained by the users. I have no control on the images themselves.

Comment: Probably you have, but have you consider using css sprites?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you consider a progressive loading slideshow whereby the images are loaded prior to being shown. Take a look at the [jQuery Cycle](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin, specifically [this example](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/add2.html) which shows how to add a slide to the slideshow after it has started (progressive) and [this one](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle/add3.html) which shows how to preload images being added after the slideshow has start.

Good Luck!

Comment: I have actually used jQuery Cycle in the past. My issue is that it doesn't come with all the bells and whistles that other sliders like Nivo offer.

Comment: Understandable; you can always look at extending Nivo to include an addSlide functionality like Cycle has.

Comment: Also found this which may be a stop-gap solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727253/getting-nivo-slider-to-start-before-all-images-are-loaded

Comment: Thx, I'll give it a try but I am afraid it's not that simple. Without load, there's a risk to break the script if it loads before the images.